# Issue Report Plugin not working in SonarQube 5.6.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

This is how i execute my sonar analysis,

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

In Sonar 4.0 i was able to generate HTML reports, But in SonarWube 5.6.1 its not working out (No errors thrown)

I have googled a lot and couldn't find an alternate plugin or any fix for this.

If some one can suggest me, that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SonarLint for Command Line](http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/index.html). The functionality was moved there.

**EDIT** SonarLint for Command Line has been dropped. The recommendation is now to use SonarLint in your IDE or Branch Analysis, which is available in [Developer Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/)($)

Comment: Thanks that helpy me out,

Comment: Using BuildBreaker, Sonarqube in preview/issues mode does not fails but fails in publish mode,
anything that you can suggest for this?

Comment: BuildBreaker works (or not) based on the Quality Gate status. By definition, the preview mode does not update the QG status.

Comment: This is the question i am taking about, if am not clear
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355630/buildbreaker-does-not-fails-in-issues-and-preview-mode-but-fails-in-publish-mode?noredirect=1#comment67998872_40355630

Comment: i want build breaker to fail even in preview or issues mode which doesn't happen

Comment: link is dead, and the main page has no links.