# BuildBreaker Does not fails in issues and preview mode but fails in publish mode - SonarQube5.6.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I am using Buildbreaker2.4 plugin in sonarQube5.6.1.

When i run the below command,

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish
```

Buildbreaker fails with critical issues

But when i run any of the below two commands, it gets passed.

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

Suggest me on what might be the problem.

Comment: SonarQube posted [this](http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/) article. Is seems the support for Buildbreaker stopped after version [5.4](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE54/Breaking+the+CI+Build).

Comment: So what is the alternate for this? i mean if quality gate fails somehow my first command fails,
But i want it to fail in preview mode as well

Answer (score 0):

for fail in preview mode you have to write your plugin '@batchside' (implements PostJob). 

1- load current quality gate properties for your project

```
WsRequest wsRequest = new GetRequest("api/qualitygates/show").setParam("id", qgId).setMediaType(MediaTypes.PROTOBUF);
```

2- read errors of your current analysis (in PostJobContext object)

```
Iterator<PostJobIssue> iterator = context.issues().iterator();
```

3- do your business, compare errors and thresold of your QG
4- finish in a exception and it will break the 'preview' build

```
 throw MessageException.of("too many errors for preview mode ..");
```